# Appscript setformula parsing error. but seems working

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to set formula in google spreadsheet cell using this code

```
function SetFormuleSettimana(row) {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var Settimane = ss.getSheetByName("Settimane"); 

   var cell = Settimane.getRange("I" + row);

   cell.setFormulaR1C1('ArrayFormula(Indice(Gruppi!A:G;Confronta(1;(G' + row + '=Gruppi!A:A)*(H' + row + '=Gruppi!B:B);0);5))');
}
```

The cell seems correctly filled with the formuala `=ArrayFormula(Indice(Gruppi!A:G;Confronta(1;(G2=Gruppi!A:A)*(H2=Gruppi!B:B);0);5))`

but I get a "Parsing Error", analyzing the formula in spreadsheet the help give correct value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### There is a [problem](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/77687116) with setting formulas with Apps Script in a language other than English.

To set your formulas programmatically, for the meantime you need to use the corresponding English names of the formulas.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The call has been modified as cell.setFormula('ArrayFormula(index(Gruppi!A:G;match(1;(' + 'G' + row + '=Gruppi!A:A)*(' + 'H' + row +  '=Gruppi!B:B);0);5))');